# CSS Issue Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am unable to display all the list items in a view because of the custom master page.

I am really struck .. I need  to sort this issue. How do I do it?

any CSS Guru's with sharepoint understanding can help me?

Comment: How do you see it now? screenshots etc etc We need more information otherwise we wont be able to help you.

Comment: Provide some more info like whats missing for example alternate rows etc

Comment: I have more than 10 columns in my list. I can see data only in first 8 columns in the display and I cannot see the remaing columns data of the list. I can see the coulumn headings but I cannot see any records in the list(last columns). Its not that there is no data, it is only because of CSS, they data is not visisble in the list. When you show only 5 coulumns of the list in the view I can see the data in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have fixed width provided some where in your CSS or you have used some colour code which is not visible to naked eye for some of the HTML tags. Sharepoint works best in % mode of width. I would suggest use firebug extension of firefox and check the CSS applied on the tags which are not visible and that will help you to resolve your problem